# Replace text in html textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have this script that matches a text on keyup in a textarea if between the minus sign.

```
    $('#notes').keyup(function() { // notes is the id of the textarea
        var regex = /\-([^\)]+)\-/gmi; // it gets the text between minus sign. Example: -text-
        var myValue = $(this).val();
        if(myValue.match(regex)){
            var reference = myValue.match(regex);
            $.ajax({
                async: false, 
                type: "POST",
                url: "scripts/script.php",
                data: { "reference" : reference },
                success: function(data) {   
                    // I need to replace the text matched by the regex with data in the textarea.
                    // I need to stop the ajax calling after success or call it only if regex is matched
                }
            }); 
        }
    });
```

When text is matched by the regex it send an ajax post call to a script that search the world in a database and returns a definition. I need to replace the text matched by the regex with data, the definition extracted by the database.

Additionally I'd like to launch the ajax POST call only if regex is matched. It works just the first time. After first match it still sending the call for each keyup.

Comment: You want to replace what the user puts into an input, while they are typing it in? I would suggest thinking of other ways, this sounds like very bad UX

Comment: ...rather use on enter

Comment: It's not an iput, it's a textarea and it's not while typing but just text between the minus signs.

Comment: so call replace like you do with match?

Comment: I tried with this, but no error and no value changed in the textarea: $((reference)[0]).replaceWith($(reference)[0], newValue ); // where newValue is = data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem adding **contenteditable="true"** to the textarea.
Below the final jquery code:

```
    var textInput = $("#notes"); // the ID of the textarea
    var triggerTime;
    $("#notes").keyup(function() { // notes is the id of the textarea
        clearTimeout(triggerTime);
        var myValue = $(this).text();
        triggerTime = setTimeout(function(){
            var regex = /\-([^\)]+)\-/gmi; // it gets the text between minus sign. Example: -text-
            if(myValue.match(regex)){
                var newValue;
                var reference = myValue.match(regex);
                $.ajax({
                    async: false, 
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "scripts/parser.php",
                    data: { "reference" : reference },
                    success: function(data) {       
                        newValue = data;    
                        console.log(newValue);
                        $('.textarea').html(function() {
                            return $(this).text().replace(reference[0], '<strong>' + newValue + '</strong>');
                        });
                    }
                }); 
            }
        }, 1000);// Call request in 1 second
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.

```
var triggerTime;
$("#notes").keyup(function() { // notes is the id of the textarea
        clearTimeout(triggerTime);
        var myValue = $(this).val();
        triggerTime = setTimeout(function(){
            var regex = /\-([^\)]+)\-/gmi; // it gets the text between minus sign. Example: -text-
            if(myValue.match(regex)){
                var reference = myValue.match(regex);
                $.ajax({
                    async: false, 
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "scripts/script.php",
                    data: { "reference" : reference },
                    success: function(data) {   
                        // I need to replace the text matched by the regex with data in the textarea.
                        // I need to stop the ajax calling after success or call it only if regex is matched
                    }
                }); 
            }
        }, 3000);// Call request in 3 second
    });
```

This is the optimized version of your code. it will wait for users to complete, and in inactivity of 3 seconds, it will generate an Ajax call.

you can change the frequency to 2000 OR 1000 (2 second and 1 second respectively).

Comment: It still making further calls when typing after match.

Comment: Do you like to stop the calls after the first call?

Comment: Yes. I'd like that the call would happen just when the regex is matched.

Comment: Currently, it should be calling on the match but after replacement with the new text, would u like to replace/remove those "-" (minus signs)?

Comment: The php script returns a phrase that should replace the -text-. But it doesn't work, so maybe is for this reason that it keeps making the call. Any suggestion for how to replace the -text- ?

Comment: You can trim the phrase at PHP end with the PHP trim() method OR you can use the regex at the javascript end while replacing the phrase.

Comment: It should work like this: while typing the -text- matched by the regex is sent to the php that returns a phrase and only this part (the -text-) should be replaced, not all the paragraph. I tried something in a previous comment, but no errors and no -text- changed...

Comment: Can there be multiple text between those minus?..  like "hello the -text- will -now- change"