# Regex for extracting each word between hyphens

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I am learning regex and trying to write a pattern that exactly matches each of the strings without'-' so that I can iterate for each of the groups and print the respective strings.

I have a string that looks like "Abcd001-wd2s-vwe1-20180e3103.txt"

I was able to write a regex for extracting Abcd001, wd2s and .txt from above text as shown below

```
(\A[^-]+)=> Abcd001
(-[^-]+-)=> wd2s
(\..*)=>.txt
```

However, I was unable to come up with the correct pattern for extracting the exact strings vwe1 and 20180e3103

It will be really helpful if you can guide me on this or if there is a better approach to achieve this?

Please note: `[^-.]+` may give me all the words separately but I am looking for an option where I have a group defined for each of these strings so that its one to one mapping.

Thanks!

Comment: You might use [`[^-]+`](https://regex101.com/r/wdQVSF/1) if you also want to match `20180e3103.txt`. That would match not a hyphen one or more times. Or for the current example use  [`\w+(?=[-.])`](https://regex101.com/r/wdQVSF/2)

Comment: @Thefourthbird: I added a note just now as after posting the question I realized, this answer may come so the question becomes more like - how I extract just vwe1 from the given string?

Comment: Change `(-[^-]+-)` to `(-[^-]+)(?=-)`

Comment: Why don't you just use `(\w+)`? Am I missing something?

Comment: @revo - This wont help me either as searching with the pattern you mentioned would give me -wd2s and -vwe1

Comment: You could use a quantifier `{2}` or `{3}` to get `vwe1` and `20180e3103` [`(?:\w+-){2}([^-.]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/WTFnLz/1) and [`(?:\w+-){3}([^-.]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/WTFnLz/2)

Comment: @Alberto: The question is how can I extract just "vwe1" from the given string?

Comment: Because both `-wd2s` and  `-vwe1` follow the same pattern. You don't have any strict rules for them. So that's what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get `vwe1` or `20180e3103` from the example data, you might use a quantifier `{2}` or `{3}` to repeat matching one or more word charcters followed by a hyphen `(?:\w+-){2}`.

Then you could capture in a group `([^-.]+)` matching not a hyphen or a dot.

[`(?:\w+-){2}([^-.]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/WTFnLz/1)

Comment: is there a difference in the notepad++ regex find and the one here https://regex101.com/r/WTFnLz/2? I tried a similar approach but notepad++ gives "Abcd001-wd2s-vwe1" as a match however, the link gives correctly what I am expecting.

Comment: If you use find using this regex, I think you get the whole match and not the separate group. If you are using notepad, can you test [`(?:\w+-){3}\K[^-.]+`](https://regex101.com/r/dHCt2A/1)

Comment: wow, awesome...can you please explain what is different in the implementation? Also for a java program which is the right implementation to use? Thank you so much for taking this through.

Comment: I don't think Java supports `\K`. In that case you would use the regex I posted and your value would be in capturing group 1. Notepad supports `\K` which means that all the characters that are previously consumed are not longer part of the match. So you match the repetition and after that you use `\K` and start matching `([^-.]+)`. That would be the only match.

Comment: @Dwarrior What could be handy is that on regex101 there is a [code generator](https://regex101.com/r/WTFnLz/1/codegen?language=java) which can give you an example of how the code could look. In Java, this could look like [Example1](http://rextester.com/SJH60305) or [Example 2](http://rextester.com/LMQH8300)

Comment: You have been very helpful in providing the guidance. I think I am still missing the last bit for my solution. Is this correct way? http://rextester.com/XET43499

Comment: @Dwarrior I think you could update [your regex](https://regex101.com/r/7LvopK/1) in [the code](http://rextester.com/IIZS90444) without using the parts with `{0}`. That would mean a [quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) repeated zero times.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below regex

`/\-([^\)]+)\-/gmi;`

Also check the similar implementation: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50336050/8179245